# Setting text background-color with transparency

Tags: css, transparency, opacity, background-color

Is it possible I can set a background-color for a text with transparency?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vH8qF/

but with transparency/opacity...

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Semi-)transparent colors can be set by using `hsla` or `rgba`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vH8qF/1/).

```
background-color: rgba(203, 233, 247, 0.5); /* 50% alpha channel*/
```

For more information, have a look at: [MDN: colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value#RGBa_%28red-green-blue-alpha%29_rgba%28R.2CG.2CB.2Ca%29)

Comment: Thank you. I knew about it I just forgot. Cheers